# detail item from didSelectRowAtIndexPath comes out as null

Tags: xcode, ios, ipad, uitableview, uipopovercontroller

Right now I have a table with a number of PDFs listed.  From the table the user can select a PDF and it will be displayed in the view.  Right now when I select and item from the table it should change the `detailView`'s detailItem to the item in the row I selected, in addition change the variable `i` to the selected row number.

Here is what my `DidSelectRowAtIndexPath` method looks like:

```
- (void)tableView:(UITableView *)aTableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {

    affirmaPDFViewController.detailItem = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@", [listOfPDF objectAtIndex:indexPath.row]];
    affirmaPDFViewController.i = indexPath.row;

    NSLog(@"%d", indexPath.row); //returns the proper value
    NSLog(@"%@", [listOfPDF objectAtIndex:indexPath.row]); //returns the proper value

    //NSLog(@"%d", affirmaPDFViewController.i); //DOES NOT return the proper value
    //NSLog(@"%@", affirmaPDFViewController.detailItem); //DOES NOT return the proper value

}
```

for the first two NSLog's, they display the proper information, however when i check the last two they come out with `affirmaPDFViewController.i` = 0 and `affirmaPDFViewController.detailItem` = null.  When i need the `affirmaPDFViewController.i`= indexPath.row, and `affirmaPDFViewController.detailItem` = the item in the row I selected.

Anyone know why they aren't coming out with the proper values?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your instance of `affirmaPDFViewController` is nil. Check the method where it's created, and remember you can set a breakpoint in the debugger to see if it's a valid object or not.

Comment: Charbonnaeau: What method would I create the controller, and how would I do so?  I am synthesizing it at the beginning of the class.  Is that what you mean by creating an instance of it?

Comment: The @synthesize keyword creates a pair of getter and setter methods which allow you to access an instance variable in your class. To actually assign an object to that instance variable you'll have to create one with the appropriate alloc / init call.

Comment: so with `affirmaPDFViewController` representing my view, and `PDFTableController` representing my popover table, would I create a new instance of the `affirmaPDFViewController` in the `viewDidLoad` method of the `PDFTableController.m` file?

Comment: View controllers are pretty heavy objects, usually you'd only create one when you need to (right before pushing it onto the screen).